# Filling a vlookup down in VBA

Tags: vba, vlookup

I'm using a vlookup to pull a date from another sheet and I'm referencing a cell in the sheet that I want it to pull to. I want to drag the vlookup down but I can't figure out how to anchor the formula so it remains the same when I drag it down. Also I'm referencing cell "I2" and then I want the Vlookup then to reference "I3" and so on, but I'm not exactly sure how to code it. Any help would be appreciated! Here's my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim StoreData As Range
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set StoreData = Sheets("List of Stores").Range("A2:C" & lastrow)

    Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140").Select
    Range("H1").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove





On Error GoTo myerrorhandler:
    Dim x
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("I2"), StoreData, 3, False)
    Range("H2").Value = x

    End With

    Dim FillFormula As Variant
    x = x + 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Select
    FillFormula = "VLookup(x), StoreData, 3, False)"
    .Range("H2:H&lastrow").Formula = FillFormula
    .Range("H&lastrow").FillDown
    End With
myerrorhandler:
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            MsgBox "Value not found"
            End If
```

I tried to make it so x would be "I2" then "I3" etc but I didn't do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  When trying to fill the same formula down a range use R1C1:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim StoreData As Range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set StoreData = Sheets("List of Stores").Range("A2:C" & lastrow)

With Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    .Range("H1").EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("H2:H" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "Vlookup(RC1," & StoreData.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1, True) & ",2,False)"
End With
```

If all you want is the value in the cells then use this:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim StoreData As Range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set StoreData = Sheets("List of Stores").Range("A2:C" & lastrow)

With Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    .Range("H1").EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("H2:H" & lastrow).Value = .Evaluate("INDEX(Vlookup(I2:I" & lastrow & "," & StoreData.Address(1, 1,,True) & ",2,False),)")
End With
```

Comment: It copied down the Vlookup text but not the actual value. I've been playing around with the code and I think I may have found a way to fix it. `Dim FillFormula As Variant
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
    k = ActiveCell
    
 
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    FillFormula = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("k"), StoreData, 3, False)
    .Range("H3:H" & lastrow).Formula = FillFormula
    .Range("H3:H" & lastrow).FillDown
   End With`

Comment: Just when I do the formula `k=activecell` it ends up erasing that cell instead of making k that value. That's the only part that I'm stuck on now.

Comment: So you just want the value?

Comment: Yeah, I want the value (it's a date), which is referencing another sheet and I just want it to copy down. Original Vlookup is (I2, storedata, 3, false) but it just needs to be able to drag down the I2 to I3 and etc. (The data range storedata is what is in another sheet)

Comment: @JForkey i just edited it again the second code should do what you want.

Comment: Wow, that made the code way shorter and easier to use, thanks so much!

Comment: I was calculating another Vlookup in a different sheet using the same data range and it just comes up as an #N/A, the code works for the first vlookup but I'm wondering why it wouldn't work for the second one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Post another question with the new code and link back to this question so we know from where you started. @JForkey

Comment: here's the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713493/vlookup-in-vba-that-drags-down